# Java SSH connect to remote machine from another remote machine

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I have already searched about this issue, analyzed several open source tools (like [Ganymed SSH-2](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/), [SSHJ](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj), [sshxcute](http://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/)) and couldn't find any solution to connect to remote machine from remote machine. What I have is:
 
1) machine B is behind firewall and ins't visible to the Internet (and not in my infrastructure)
2) I can connect to machine B from machine A (which is also not in mine infrastrucutre) 
3) I need to connect from my machine to machine A (pretty easy solution and any from listed SSH libs can do that) and from machine A to machine B (probably I lack knowledge about SSH protocol or none of listed tools can do it?).
I have found one lib which is allowing described connection scenario which is [J2SSH](http://www.javassh.com/products/j2ssh-maverick), but it is not free. The question is, are there any free libs which would allow me to do described connection?

Comment: Did you take a look at Jsch? I don't know if they implement what you would like, but it is widely used for SSH.

Comment: Haven't checked JSCH, going to study its documentation now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to JSch's sample program http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html.

```
$ wget http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java
$ wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch.jar/0.1.48/jsch-0.1.48.jar
$ javac -cp ./jsch-0.1.48.jar:. JumpHosts.java
$ java -cp ./jsch-0.1.48.jar:. JumpHosts usrA@hostA usrB@hostB
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about SSH tunnels. It's easy enough to do what you want. Have a look at this tutorial http://www.rzg.mpg.de/networkservices/ssh-tunnelling-port-forwarding. 'gate' and 'work' are roughly equivalent to 'B' and 'A'.

Comment: Seems like it was lack of my knowledge of SSH. But from what I see (and probably I would get the same problem using for example J2SSH) are firewalls :D